# Flutter null-safety conditionals in object methods

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm just working through this whole null-safety mode with my Flutter project and unsure what the difference is with `?` and `!` in calls to object methods.

For example, the hint was to add a `!` conditional. Here's an example I have right now, and I'm unsure if this should be a `?` or a `!` at the `findNbr!.replaceAll()`.

```
Future checkItem({String? findNbr}) async {
  int? x = int.tryParse(findNbr!.replaceAll('-', ''));

  ...
```

Does this mean `replaceAll()` will not run if findNbr is null?

Or should it be a `?` instead?  findNbr?.replaceAll()
EDIT: I just noticed I cannot use findNbr?, it's telling String? can't be assigned parameter String.

Or does it mean I say it's not null and run it anyway?

For your information, I have not come close to running my app yet so I have no idea if it even works. But I figure I better know what it's doing before get too much more done. I'm still in the process of converting everything and there's 75-100 dart files.  I'm not sure I get the point of it all to be honest, because I just add `?` to everything, so its all nullable anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Future checkItem({String? findNbr}) async {
>   int? x = int.tryParse(findNbr!.replaceAll('-', ''));
>
>   ...
> ```
>
> Does this mean `replaceAll()` will not run if findNbr is null?

Correct.  If `findNbr` is `null`, then `findNbr!` will throw a runtime exception.  That would be bad, especially since `checkItem`'s function signature advertises that `findNbr` is allowed to be `null`, and therefore it would violate callers' expectations.

> Or should it be a `?` instead?  findNbr?.replaceAll()
> EDIT: I just noticed I cannot use findNbr?, it's telling String? can't be assigned parameter String.

You can't use `findNbr?.replaceAll(...)` because if `findNbr` is `null`, then it would be invoking `int.tryParse(null)`, but `int.tryParse` is not allowed to take a `null` argument.

What you need to do is *one* of:

- Make `findNbr` no longer optional:

  ```dart
  Future checkItem({required String findNbr}) async {
    int? x = int.tryParse(findNbr.replaceAll('-', ''));
    ...
  ```
- Allow `findNbr` to be optional but have a non-null default value:

  ```dart
  Future checkItem({String findNbr = ''}) async {
    int? x = int.tryParse(findNbr.replaceAll('-', ''));
    ...
  ```
- Allow `findNbr` to be optional but explicitly decide what to do if it is null.  For example:

  ```dart
  Future checkItem({String? findNbr}) async {
    int? x = findNbr == null ? null : int.tryParse(findNbr.replaceAll('-', ''));
    ...
  ```

> I'm not sure I get the point of it all to be honest, because I just add `?` to everything, so its all nullable anyway.

If you blindly add `?` to all types and add `!` to all variables, then yes, null-safety would be pointless: doing that would give you the same behavior as Dart before null-safety.

The point of null-safety is to prevent things that *shouldn't* be `null` from ever being `null`.  You could have written such code before, but **without null-safety, that meant performing *runtime* `null` checks** (e.g. `assert(x != null);`, `if (x != null) { ... }`, or relying on a null-pointer-exception to crash the program if `null` was used where it wasn't expected). **Null-safety means that such checks now can be done at *build-time* by static analysis**, which means that errors can be caught earlier and more completely.  Furthermore, whereas previously functions needed to explicitly document whether arguments and return values were allowed to be `null` (and inadequate or incorrect documentation could be a source of errors), now they're self-documenting in that regard.  It's just like using `int foo(String s)` versus `dynamic foo(dynamic s)`; using strong types catches errors earlier and better describes the function's contract.

I recommend reading [Understanding Null Safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety) if you haven't already done so.

Comment: Awesome answer, and a solution!  After I wrote this question I figured I'd have to do some kind of findNbr != null check.  It's just the combined variable with a function "variable!.function()" thing that confused me and I didn't see that specific variation in docs.  And yes, I'm not blindly adding ? operators.  I do take each one and assess, tweak it and remove a null check, which is nice.  But there's a huge amount of functions with optional arguments and cases where variables can indeed be null, like database records.  I appreciate you pointing it out, along with the null-safety info. Thx!

Comment: @gregthegeek I forgot about a third way to deal with it: by adding a non-null default value.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to advice you to use the `!` operator, also the called bang operator, as little as possible. You should only use this operator when the dart analyser is wrong and you know for 100% that the value will `never` be null.

Below is an example of where the dart analyser would be wrong and you should use the bang operator.

```dart
// We have a class dog with a nullable name.
class Dog {
  String? name;
  
  Dog({this.name});
}

void main() {
  // We create a dog without a name.
  final dog = Dog();
  
  // We assign the dog a name.
  dog.name = 'George';
  
  // The dart analyser will show an error because it can't know if the
  // name of the object is not null.
  //
  // Will throw: `A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a
  // variable of type 'String'`.
  String myDogsName = dog.name;

  // To avoid this, you should use the bang operator because you `know` it
  // is not null.
  String myDogsName = dog.name!;
}
```

The `?` operator simply tells Dart that the value `can` be null. So every time you want to place a `?` operator, ask yourself, can this value ever be null?

The null safety features in Dart are mainly created for helping the developer remember when a value `can` be null. Dart will now simply tell you when you made a variable nullable in order to force null checks or default values for example.